# Can we host a springboot application on github pages?

Tags: spring-boot, github

I have written as small springboot app that does basic CRUD(GET,POST,PUT,etc). Is it possible to host it using githubpages or github-pages can be used only for deploying simple html pages?

Comment: No. You can only host pages on there not applications and especially not Java based applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not. GitHub pages can only host static content (HTML, CSS, JS, text). This excludes any runtimes, such as the JVM required for Java or NodeJS.

[About GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages):

> GitHub Pages is a *static* site hosting service that takes HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files straight from a repository on GitHub, optionally runs the files through a build process, and publishes a website. [emphasis mine]